# how to rotate dom element by a set amount (pure js)

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am attempting to rotate an item continuously.
This code works for rotating a 'second' hand for a clock:

```
    function setTime() {
    const timer = new Date();
    const getSeconds = timer.getSeconds();
    const degrees = (getSeconds/60)*360;
    console.log('check: ', degrees);
    globe.style.transform = `rotate(${degrees}deg)`;

}
const globe = document.querySelector(".logo");

setInterval(setTime, 200);
```

This code allows me to rotate the item. 
However, I would like to rotate the item faster than this, so I have tried changing timer from 1000ms to 200ms and getting *getMilliseconds()* instead of *getSeconds()* and incrementing, which doesn't work. 
I have also tried setting the rotation to increment without using the actual time, and the dom element that I grabbed (.logo) rotates initially once, and then never rotates again:

```
function setTime() {
    const rotateDegs = 10;
    globe.style.transform = `rotate(${rotateDegs}deg)`;
}

const globe = document.querySelector(".logo");

setInterval(setTime, 200);
```

How do I get my item to continuously rotate by any amount near 30rpm or more?

I would like to use only js and/ or css no jquery. 
Thank you

Comment: just change this setInterval(setTime, 200); to setInterval(setTime, 100);

Answer (score 0):

Also  answer in pure JavaScript.

If yo need to increase rpm like you say **more than 30** just manipulate the `value` variable

```js
let val = 0;

rotateItem = item => {
    item.style.transform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
    item.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
    item.style.mozTransform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
    val += 10; 
}
setInterval(() => rotateItem(document.getElementById('foo'), 0) , 100);
```

```css
#foo {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px dashed blue;

}
```

```html
<img  id="foo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Simple_light_bulb_graphic.png">
```